# how to arrange elements in UIStackView in realtime?

Tags: swift, uikit, uistackview, ios14, xcode12

I have a stackView with horizontal axis and I have UIView inside it, I kinda created a graph from that ,[image: Bars image]

the red one bars are the UIViews and the gray background is the stackView(referred as mainStackView in code) , Now I want to move that bar in realtime , I am trying to make a sorting visualiser but I dont know how do I do that
In UIKit (everything is programmatic in live playground), here is the source code of the main file
Main file

```
                if (arrayToSort[j].frame.size.height > arrayToSort[j+1].frame.size.height){
    //               swap
                    var temp:UIView!
                    temp = arrayToSort[j]
                    arrayToSort[j] = arrayToSort[j+1]
                    arrayToSort[j+1] = temp
                    emptyStackView()
                    fillStackView(sortdArr: arrayToSort)
//                    delay here
                    
                }
```

Here is the source code for HomeViewController

```
import UIKit

public class HomeViewController:UIViewController{
    let stackView:UIStackView = {
        let st = UIStackView()
        st.axis = .horizontal
        st.alignment = .center
        st.distribution = .fill
        st.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        st.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        st.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        st.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        st.spacing = 10
        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return st
    }()
    let generateButton:UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Generate Array", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.92, green: 0.30, blue: 0.29, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let BubbleSort:UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("BubbleSort", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.41, green: 0.43, blue: 0.88, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let MergeSort:UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("MergeSort", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.10, green: 0.16, blue: 0.34, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let InsertionSort:UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("InsertionSort", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.19, green: 0.22, blue: 0.32, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let SelectionSort:UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("SelectionSort", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.51, green: 0.20, blue: 0.44, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let mainStackView:UIStackView = {
        let st = UIStackView()
        st.backgroundColor = .gray
        st.axis = .horizontal
        st.distribution = .fillEqually
        st.alignment = .bottom
        st.spacing = 1
        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return st
    }()
    let baseView:UIView = {
        let vw = UIView()
        vw.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.07, green: 0.54, blue: 0.65, alpha: 1.00)
        vw.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vw.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        vw.layer.masksToBounds = true
        vw.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
        return vw
    }()
    public override   func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        view.addSubview(mainStackView)
        view.addSubview(baseView)
        edgesForExtendedLayout = []
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(generateButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(BubbleSort)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(MergeSort)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(InsertionSort)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(SelectionSort)
        
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        
        baseView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor,constant: -2).isActive = true
        baseView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor,constant: 5).isActive = true
        baseView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor,constant: -5).isActive = true
        
        mainStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        mainStackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        mainStackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        mainStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseView.topAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        setButtons()
        buildRandomArray()
        
    }
    // MARK:- Actions
    func setButtons(){
        generateButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(generatePressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        BubbleSort.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bubbleSort), for: .touchUpInside)
        MergeSort.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mergeSort), for: .touchUpInside)
        InsertionSort.addTarget(self, action: #selector(insertionSort), for: .touchUpInside)
        SelectionSort.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectionSort), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    func buildRandomArray(){
        var randomNumber :CGFloat!
        for _ in 1..<41{
            let viewStick:UIView = {
                let v = UIView()
                v.backgroundColor = .red
                v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                randomNumber = CGFloat(Int.random(in: 160...600))
                v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: randomNumber).isActive = true
                v.frame.size.height = randomNumber
                return v
            }()
            mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(viewStick)
        }
        
    }
    @objc func generatePressed(){
        
        emptyStackView()
        buildRandomArray()
        print("Generating Array.....")
    }
    
    @objc func bubbleSort(){
        
        let n = mainStackView.arrangedSubviews.count
        var arrayToSort = mainStackView.arrangedSubviews
        
        for i in 0..<n-1{
            for j in 0..<n-i-1 {
                if (arrayToSort[j].frame.size.height > arrayToSort[j+1].frame.size.height){
                    //               swap
                    var temp:UIView!
                    temp = arrayToSort[j]
                    arrayToSort[j] = arrayToSort[j+1]
                    arrayToSort[j+1] = temp
                    
                    self.emptyStackView()
                    self.fillStackView(sortdArr: arrayToSort)
                    //                    delay here
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        print("array sorted")
    }
    
    @objc func mergeSort(){
        print("Merge Sort.....")
    }
    
    @objc func insertionSort(){
        print("insertion Sort.....")
    }
    
    @objc func selectionSort(){
        print("selection Sort.....")
    }
    func emptyStackView(){
        for element in mainStackView.arrangedSubviews {
            mainStackView.removeArrangedSubview(element)
        }
    }
    func fillStackView(sortdArr:[UIView]){
        for vw in sortdArr {
            mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(vw)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `UIStackView` animation as you want is not the best way to do so, It has a "strange“ animation. It' be better with a `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the UI in a loop, you have to give UIKit a chance to run.

For example, this:

```
for i in 1...200 {
    someView.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(i)
}
```

will **NOT** "slide the view" to the right - it will cause the view to "jump" from `x: 1` to `x: 200`.

So, in your loop where you're trying to visualize the sorting process, nothing on the screen will update until you have completed the loop.

To have something happen each time through, you can use a Timer.

With the previous example, you could do something like this:

```
var i = 1
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true) { timer in
    someView.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(i)
    i += 1
    if i > 200 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Now the view will "slide slowly" across the screen.

So, you need to refactor your sorting code with a timer.

I made some edits to your code to let you see ***one approach*** to this task. Give it a try (it will run in a playground), and inspect the code and //comments. Changes don't start until the `buildRandomArray()` function:

---

**Edit** - I made a few changes to this code...

- has an array of "sample values" to make it easier to re-run
- added a "Reset" button to re-run with the original values
- when using sample values, bars are now labels to make it clearer that the bars are being "moved"
- implemented Insertion Sort

Worth noting: When running this in a playground, button taps while a sort is active are not very responsive. Works much betting with an iPad Simulator or Device.

```
public class SortViewController:UIViewController{
    let stackView:UIStackView = {
        let st = UIStackView()
        st.axis = .horizontal
        st.alignment = .center
        st.distribution = .fillEqually
        st.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        st.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        st.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        st.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        st.spacing = 10
        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return st
    }()
    let generateButton:UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Generate", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.92, green: 0.30, blue: 0.29, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let resetButton:UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Reset", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.25, green: 0.75, blue: 0.29, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let BubbleSort:UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Bubble", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.41, green: 0.43, blue: 0.88, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let MergeSort:UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Merge", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.10, green: 0.16, blue: 0.34, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let InsertionSort:UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Insertion", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.19, green: 0.22, blue: 0.32, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let SelectionSort:UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Selection", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.51, green: 0.20, blue: 0.44, alpha: 1.00)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38).isActive = true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let mainStackView:UIStackView = {
        let st = UIStackView()
        st.backgroundColor = .gray
        st.axis = .horizontal
        st.distribution = .fillEqually
        st.alignment = .bottom
        st.spacing = 1
        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return st
    }()
    let baseView:UIView = {
        let vw = UIView()
        vw.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.07, green: 0.54, blue: 0.65, alpha: 1.00)
        vw.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vw.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        vw.layer.masksToBounds = true
        vw.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
        return vw
    }()
    public override   func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        view.addSubview(mainStackView)
        view.addSubview(baseView)
        edgesForExtendedLayout = []
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(generateButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(resetButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(BubbleSort)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(MergeSort)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(InsertionSort)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(SelectionSort)
        
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        
        baseView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor,constant: -2).isActive = true
        baseView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor,constant: 5).isActive = true
        baseView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor,constant: -5).isActive = true
        
        mainStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        mainStackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        mainStackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        mainStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseView.topAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        setButtons()
        buildRandomArray()
        
    }
    // MARK:- Actions
    func setButtons(){
        generateButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(generatePressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        resetButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(resetPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        BubbleSort.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bubbleSort), for: .touchUpInside)
        MergeSort.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mergeSort), for: .touchUpInside)
        InsertionSort.addTarget(self, action: #selector(insertionSort), for: .touchUpInside)
        SelectionSort.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectionSort), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    let sampleValues: [Int] = [
        150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 375, 400, 425, 450, 475, 500
    ]
    
    var currentArray: [UIView] = []
    
    let barColor: UIColor = .cyan
    let barHighlight: UIColor = .yellow
    
    let timerInterval: TimeInterval = 0.10
    
    func buildRandomArray(){
        
        // we can populate the stack view much quicker by generating an array of views
        //  and then looping through that array to add them as arrangedSubviews
        currentArray = []
        
        // for ease during dev, use a set of predefined values
        if true {
            let hh = sampleValues.shuffled()
            hh.forEach { h in
                let viewStick: UILabel = {
                    let v = UILabel()
                    v.backgroundColor = barColor
                    v.text = "\(h)"
                    v.textAlignment = .center
                    v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(h)).isActive = true
                    return v
                }()
                currentArray.append(viewStick)
            }
        } else {
            var randomNumber :CGFloat!
            for _ in 1..<41{
                let viewStick:UIView = {
                    let v = UIView()
                    v.backgroundColor = barColor
                    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    randomNumber = CGFloat(Int.random(in: 160...500))
                    v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: randomNumber).isActive = true
                    return v
                }()
                currentArray.append(viewStick)
            }
        }
        fillStackView(sortdArr: currentArray)
        
    }
    
    @objc func generatePressed(){
        
        // stop the timer if a sort is currently running
        timer?.invalidate()
        
        print("Generating Array.....")
        
        emptyStackView()
        buildRandomArray()
        
    }
    
    @objc func resetPressed(){
        
        // stop the timer if a sort is currently running
        timer?.invalidate()
        
        print("Resetting.....")
        
        fillStackView(sortdArr: currentArray)
        
    }
    
    var timer: Timer?
    
    @objc func bubbleSort(){
        print("Bubble Sort....")
        
        // if a sort is running, stop it and reset the bars
        if let t = timer, t.isValid {
            resetPressed()
        }
        
        var j: Int = 0
        
        var didSwap: Bool = false
        
        var lastBarToCheck: Int = mainStackView.arrangedSubviews.count - 1
        
        // set current bar to first bar
        var curBar = mainStackView.arrangedSubviews[0]
        // set new current bar background to barHighlight
        curBar.backgroundColor = barHighlight
        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timerInterval, repeats: true) { timer in
            
            // if we have more bars to check
            if j < lastBarToCheck {
                
                if self.mainStackView.arrangedSubviews[j].frame.height > self.mainStackView.arrangedSubviews[j+1].frame.height {
                    // next bar is shorter than current bar, so
                    // swap the bar positions
                    self.mainStackView.insertArrangedSubview(curBar, at: j + 1)
                    // set the didSwap flag
                    didSwap = true
                } else {
                    // next bar is taller
                    // set current bar background back to barColor
                    curBar.backgroundColor = self.barColor
                    // set current bar to next bar
                    curBar = self.mainStackView.arrangedSubviews[j+1]
                    // set new current bar background to barHighlight
                    curBar.backgroundColor = self.barHighlight
                }
                j += 1
                
            } else {
                
                if !didSwap {
                    
                    // no bars were swapped, so
                    // set current bar back to barColor
                    curBar.backgroundColor = self.barColor
                    // stop the looping
                    timer.invalidate()
                    print("Done!")
                    
                } else {
                    
                    // at least one swap occurred, so
                    // decrement number of bars to check
                    lastBarToCheck -= 1
                    // reset index
                    j = 0
                    // set current bar back to barColor
                    curBar.backgroundColor = self.barColor
                    // set current bar background to first bar
                    curBar = self.mainStackView.arrangedSubviews[j]
                    // set new current bar background to barHighlight
                    curBar.backgroundColor = self.barHighlight
                    // reset swap flag
                    didSwap = false
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    @objc func mergeSort(){
        print("Merge Sort.....")
    }
    
    @objc func insertionSort(){
        print("Insertion Sort.....")
        
        // if a sort is running, stop it and reset the bars
        if let t = timer, t.isValid {
            resetPressed()
        }
        
        var index: Int = 1
        var position: Int = 1
        
        // set current bar to index bar
        var curBar = mainStackView.arrangedSubviews[index]
        // set new current bar background to barHighlight
        curBar.backgroundColor = barHighlight
        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timerInterval, repeats: true) { timer in
            
            // if we have more bars to check
            if index < self.mainStackView.arrangedSubviews.count {
                // if we're not at the left-most bar
                if position > 0 {
                    // if bar-to-the-left is taller than current bar
                    if self.mainStackView.arrangedSubviews[position - 1].frame.height > curBar.frame.height {
                        // move current bar one position to the left
                        self.mainStackView.insertArrangedSubview(curBar, at: position - 1)
                        position -= 1
                    } else {
                        // bar-to-the-left is shorter than current bar
                        index += 1
                        position = index
                        // set current bar background back to barColor
                        curBar.backgroundColor = self.barColor
                        // if we're not finished
                        if index < self.mainStackView.arrangedSubviews.count {
                            // set current bar to next bar
                            curBar = self.mainStackView.arrangedSubviews[index]
                            // set new current bar background to barHighlight
                            curBar.backgroundColor = self.barHighlight
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // we're at the left-most bar
                    // increment index
                    index += 1
                    position = index
                    // set current bar background back to barColor
                    curBar.backgroundColor = self.barColor
                    // if we have more bars to check
                    if index < self.mainStackView.arrangedSubviews.count {
                        // set current bar to next bar
                        curBar = self.mainStackView.arrangedSubviews[index]
                        // set new current bar background to barHighlight
                        curBar.backgroundColor = self.barHighlight
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // we've reached the end of the array
                // stop the looping
                timer.invalidate()
                print("Done!")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    @objc func selectionSort(){
        print("selection Sort.....")
    }

    func emptyStackView(){
        mainStackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach {
            $0.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    func fillStackView(sortdArr:[UIView]){
        sortdArr.forEach { vw in
            vw.backgroundColor = self.barColor
            mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(vw)
        }
    }
}
```

A tip related to stack views and their `arrangedSubviews`... you don't have to clear and re-populate the stack view to rearrange the views.

For example, if I add 10 labels to a stack view:

```
    // add 10 arranged subviews
    for i in 0..<10 {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "\(i)"
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
    }
```

it will look like this:

[image]

If I want to swap the 4th and 5th views, I can do it like this:

```
    //  (arrays are zero-based)
    stackView.insertArrangedSubview(stackView.arrangedSubviews[3], at: 4)
```

and I get:

[image]

Comment: hey @DonMag , the timer will run like infinite loop right ? , I mean unless we invalidate the timer , it will keep looping ?

Comment: @YuvrajAgarkar - yes, the timer will run until it is invalidated. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer

Comment: can I implement this method for Insertion and Merge sort too?? , I actually worried about insertion sort because it contains Recursion ..!!

Comment: @YuvrajAgarkar - the idea of using a Timer to allow UI updates inside a loop has nothing to do with what you're actually *doing* in that loop. To visualize an insertion or merge sort (or anything else), you need to first decide what you want to *show*, then write your code to perform each step during each Timer iteration. Start working on it... if you run into trouble, post *that specific problem* as a new question.

Comment: @YuvrajAgarkar - I went ahead an implemented an example of Insertion Sort, as well as made some other changes to make things clearer. See the **Edit** notes in my answer.